# Counting identical values in two columns, aware of duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two columns of data in Excel, say

```
a   a
b   d
c   x
d   b
b   d
```

I need to find the number of matches between the two columns, but only counting unique matches. In the example, the answer should be 3, matching one a, one b (not two!) and one d (also not two!). I've tried

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A:A,B:B,0))))
```

but it counts b twice (or d if I apply it the other way around).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem is even more complex:

```
a a
b d
c x
d b
b d
a a
```

This should return 4, since a matches twice and b and d match once each. I haven't figured out how to do it in one formula, but putting this

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)=1,MIN(COUNTIF(A:A,A1),COUNTIF(B:B,A1)),0)
```

in the next column, pulling it down and then summing it up solved it "good enough" for now.

Comment: This should be an Edit of your original post, not a new post.  And why do you count `a` twice?  It would seem that the two `a a`'s are not unique.  I guess I don't understand what you mean by **unique**